# js Regex replace first part

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry, for that (but I´m a regex noob)

in js how would one replace the first folder in a url string.

Pseudo Code:

```
Replace at start of string: /any-amount-of-characters/ with nothing
```

Examples

```
$path = '/xyz/abc/';
```

should result in

```
$path = 'abc/';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\/[^/]*\/
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/15

```
var re = /^\/[^\/]*\//g;
var str = '/xyz/abc/';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: create! Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use match the start of the string using `^`:

```
$path = '/xyz/abc/';
$path = $path.replace(/^\/?[^\/]*\//, '');
```

Broken down:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/?` - optional leading `/` (remove the `?` if required)
- `[^\/]*` - any number of characters except `/` (use `+` instead of `*` if you there must be at least 1 character)
- `\/` trailing `/`